# LottieAnimation(url: ) not animated first time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, lottie

I want to present Lottie animation view in swiftUI. But unfortunately, it doesn't animate the view when it appears on the view first time. If it disappears, then appears again, then the animation displayed. I am looking for the solution of how effectively I can present Lottie animation from URL in the view. The code I have written is the following:

```
struct LottieView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    let animationView: LottieAnimationView
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url // URL(string: "https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_GoeyCV7pi2.json")!
        self.animationView = LottieAnimationView(url: url) { _ in
            
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        animationView.play()
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(animationView)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        uiView.removeAllSubviews()
        uiView.addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        animationView.animationSpeed = 1.0
        animationView.play()
    }
}
```